# html function doesn't work with any event

Tags: javascript, html

The following code does not work without `onclick` or something I can click like if I write an a and then I make `onclick="getIPs()"` then it will work but without anything it won't. I don't know why it doesn't just write the ip without any events.

```
 <p id="adress" class="adress"></p>
           <script>
            async function getIPs() {
            try {
                const res = await fetch('https://api.ipify.org?format=json');
                const jsonObj = await res.json();
                document.getElementById('adress').textContent = jsonObj.ip;
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
            }
    </script>
```

Comment: Please read [a tutorial about functions](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions): “Defining _a function does not execute it. Defining it names the function and specifies what to do when the function is called.”_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've defined your function but you never call it. Now you need to call it by event or in form load `getIPs();`:

```js
async function getIPs() {
  try {
    const res = await fetch('https://api.ipify.org?format=json');
    const jsonObj = await res.json();
    document.getElementById('adress').textContent = jsonObj.ip;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

getIPs()
```

```html
<p id="adress" class="adress"></p>
```